# Using Rin-gameboy emulator with VisualBoy Advance

Tags: emulation, game-boy

I started playing Pokemon with my Android phone. I used my cartridge image with the [RIN gameboy emulator](https://github.com/kdevkdev/rin/blob/master/jni/gb/gb.c#L167). It's a port of the PSP one.

My save games (when uncompressed) have 70KB.

On [Visual Boy Advance](http://vba.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vba/VisualBoyAdvance/src/gb/GB.cpp?revision=1.29&view=markup#l3500) (which I'd like to play when not on my phone, and to do trades with myself :) uses savefiles that are 32KB.

Are those standard formats? Do I have any hopes of using one with the other?

I really thought every emulator would just make a binary dump of the sram or something :(

I can give more info on the contents of the files to try to identify the differences (if the sizes aren't a dead giveaway for the initiated). I'm also willing to spend some time to make a patch to the offending one (assuming at least one of those emulators simply dump SRAM).

---

**Edit:**
I tried to extract 32KB (or 32,768 bits, exact size of the Advance Boy saves and dat dumps) from the end of the 70KB file and now Advance Boy let's me import the file as flash or battery state without errors. But it's the same as just resetting, nothing changes on the saved states.

The command below:

`tail -c 32768 PokemonRed.android.stat | less > PokemonRed.android.sav`

will now search for the header of the 32KB files into the 70KB one.

---

**Edit 2:**

Here is the [link for dumping save format](http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/GB).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Virtual Boy Advance likes to format it's .sav's differently than things like no$gba and RIN (Which I have on PSP, so I'll be using that as reference, they shouldn't be too different).

Virtual Boy Advance has an option in the "File" drop-down menu called "Import." If you're taking the actual save data, you'll select "Battery file" from the "Import" sub-menu. If you're trying to get a save state, load the state from file in the the "Load State" sub-menu of "File."

If it can't convert the RIN file, try doing an export in RIN, and if that isn't an option, I think that no$gba would be able to convert the RIN file into something VBA could read, or you could just use no$gba, though I definitely prefer VBA.